# How can you describe someone who gives up too easily?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

A friend of mine said that he was a cynic. I had told him that he was giving up too easily. In this situation, the worst case outcome was rejection, which logically speaking, was equivalent to not trying in the first place.

I want to say, "No, you aren't cynical, you are X," or "No, you aren't a cynic, you are a(n) X."

The closest I can come up with is unmotivated or intimidated.

**What word describes a person who gives up too easily?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A [defeatist](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/defeatist_1?q=defeatist) expects to fail, and therefor, either does not try at all or tries in a half-hearted manner.

Answer (score 22):

"No, you aren't a cynic, you are a quitter."

Comment: Indeed this is the [top answer when you google "a person who gives up too easily"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/quitter)!

Comment: Ow! I hope the OP's friend is a _good_ friend.

Answer (score 6):

You can say they're *faint-hearted* or *faint of heart* ("faint heart never won fair lady"), or simply too *yielding*.

Answer (score 6):

The word is Pusillanimous

Dictionary.com describes it as follows

> pu·sil·lan·i·mous   [pyoo-suh-lan-uh-muhs]  adjective
>
> 1.lacking courage or resolution; cowardly; faint-hearted; timid.
>
> 2.proceeding from or indicating a cowardly spirit.

Comment: I like this word. It doesn't quite describe the "giving up easily" part. I could say, however, that he is a pusillanimous quitter.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative is to say he's a wimp.

Answer (score 3):

A person who is **demoralized** may give up easily.  You wouldn't typically use it without some reference to what caused it however.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like your friend is being ***[chicken](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/chicken?q=chicken)***.

You could also say he *chickened out*.

If he's a really close friend, you might even call him *[chickenshit](http://www.wordnik.com/words/chickenshit?suggested_from=chicken%20shit)*.

Comment: but **afraid** of doing something is very different from **giving up** upon failure.

Answer (score 2):

Or, you might bide your time a bit, and when your friend starts making specific excuses, you can then spring the proverb on him, "Argue for your limitations, and they are yours."