# What is a word that means "easy to give up"?

Tags: meaning, synonyms, single-word-requests

What is a word that means 
"easy to give up"?

For example, "A person that would give up is more likely to lose a basketball game than a person that never gives up."

Comment: Give up what?  To whom?

Comment: a person that gives up on everything.  this means that they don't really try.

Comment: Related: [How can you describe someone who gives up too easily?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57591/how-can-you-describe-someone-who-gives-up-too-easily) and [What's a word that describes a person that easily gives up but is easily fired up too?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/272427/whats-a-word-that-describes-a-person-that-easily-gives-up-but-is-easily-fired-u).

Comment: You should edit your post and add your comment, and provide a sentence where you show how you would use this 'word'.

Comment: So you want an adjective to describe a person who gives up easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A person who surrenders easily, expects or is excessively ready to accept failure is a **defeatist**.

> Defeatism is the acceptance of defeat without struggle, often with
>   negative connotations.

Answer (score 0):

Surrender

: to agree to stop fighting, hiding, resisting, etc., because you know that you will not win or succeed

: to give the control or use of (something) to someone else

: to allow something (such as a habit or desire) to influence or control you

MW definition

Answer (score 0):

I would consider the adjective "spiritless".

> Lacking courage, vigour, or vivacity.

Examples:

> "Ruth and I played a spiritless game of Scrabble."
>
> "Jonathan was a spiritless individual, who gave up on his work too easily."